# How can I split an R file into 2 by date

Tags: r

I would like to compare my data before and after a date, but can't work out how to create two data sets before and after the date the date.

Thanks for any advice that you can give

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data in a data frame or tibble, with your date in a column, then you can use filter.

```
library(dplyr)

# give it a date to split by
date_to_split <- "2020-07-20"

# an example dataset
tb <- tibble(
  a = lubridate::today() + runif(1e3) * 30,
  b = 1:1e3,
  c = runif(1e3),
  d = sample(letters, 1e3, replace = TRUE)
)

tb1 <- tb %>% filter(a<date_to_split)
tb2 <- tb %>% filter(a>=date_to_split)
```

You should now have two tibbles. tb1 will have one set of the data and tb2 will contain the other, split by the date you give it.